# Constant cannot find module x error. What questions should I be asking?

Tags: python, import, module, pip

I am being plagued by this error:

ImportError: No module named foo

It seems to come up somewhat randomly. I install various modules using PIP and sometimes they are found by import and sometimes they are not. What commands can I try to force the installation of these non-working modules into every possible nook and cranny to make sure that I always have access to them?

Or another question, what can I do to make this work?

Or another question, what diagnostics can I run to figure out what my real problem is?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: If you have various utility modules that you use frequently, consider [packages](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/#packages).

Comment: Do the packages you have pip installed and are giving ImportErrors show up if you run `pip freeze`? (this shows the packages which you have installed in your environment) (also if you're not using virtual environments you really should - take a look here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)

Comment: @Inti

To answer all questions, using OSX Mavericks and Python 2.7.5

When I run pip freeze it does display all expected modules and some of those are not found by the import action (but not all of them)

I have just started using virtualenv and the pip freeze is run from inside the ENV

Comment: @Pinwheeler If `pip freeze` shows them all then I guess they are all installed in locations which are on your path so should be fine to import. I don't know what else to check. Are you running your script from the same shell that you ran the pip freeze in, with your virtualenv activated...?
My only other suggestion would be to create a new virtualenv, install your requirements there and see how that goes.

Comment: @Inti what does it mean to say "from the same shell" and how would I find out that information?

Comment: @inti Wanted to follow up because I finally figured it out.

Turns out, I had pip installed without installing either easy_install or setup_tools. I can't remember which one is the dependency. Anyway, once I installed one of those two packages I was able to do anything.